In D&D, do the gods embodying various alignments *see* themselves as embodying and advocating for those alignments along their other interests?
Depictions of the gods of D&D (across game materials, novels, etc.) might be inconsistent, but as far as I can tell gods acknowledged in game books always get associated with an alignment, and that alignment seems to be an important component of who they are. It aligns with where they reside on the outer planes, for example.
Gods also have qualities that may be more important to them, such as their portfolios. But I'm wondering how much the components of alignment are acknowledged by the gods. The gods of magic in Dragonlance, for example, seem to actively want to uphold Good, Evil, or Neutrality with regards to magic usage.
If the Gods do take ownership in some way of perpetuating their alignments, are there examples of them spelling out what a given alignment means? Does Asmodeus have a view of Lawfulness, or Evil, that's nuanced compared to other Lawful and/or Evil gods, and advocate for his vision of those alignment components?
References to game texts or novels are all fine, though supporting evidence is of course needed for any opinions. Per the tags, please focus on 5th edition, 2014 preferred but 2024 is fine too.

Note to answerers:  Alignment questions usually get closed, for good reason.  I am not voting to close (yet) because I think there is a path to good answers.  But as a reminder:  This is not a platform to pontificate on your personal theories of alignment, or how you think the game should handle this question.  Good answers are going to be backed up with textual evidence.

Reminder to everyone that answers, partial answers, suggestions on where to find an answer, frame challenges, ideas that could be expanded into an answer, and general advice to the asker do not belong in comments.

Gods in 5e generally don't further their alignment except within the remit of their portfolio.
To begin with, according to the Dungeon Master's Guide (2014), D&D's gods actively promote their portfolio. Page 10:

In the Greyhawk setting, Heironeous is a god of valor who calls clerics and paladins to his service and encourages them to spread the ideals of honorable warfare, chivalry, and justice in society. Even in the midst of his everlasting war with his brother Hextor, god of war and tyranny, Heironeous promotes his own portfolio: war fought nobly and in the cause of justice.

What you're effectively asking is if D&D's gods consider their alignment part of their portfolio.
The gods' portfolios aren't so well-detailed in fifth edition sources. However, in D&D 3rd edition, many (but not all!) gods had alignment aspects either as Domains granted to their clerics, or explicitly stated as part of their portfolio. For example, according to Deities and Demigods, Lolth has the Evil domain and evil as part of her portfolio. By Forgotten Realms continuity, at least, these are the same gods as the ones in fifth edition, although the gods may behave somewhat differently toward the people in the 5e era.
However, you no longer see that spelled out so clearly in 5th edition sources. The Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide gives a lot of detail on the Faerûnian deities, including their alignment, but not whether their alignment is part of that which they actively promote. You can only infer it; e.g. Cyric, chaotic evil god of lies, has the Trickery domain, and clerics' holy symbols have skulls on them, so he's probably one of the baddies.
Confusing the issue further, clerics in 5e are no longer required to have an alignment close to their deity's alignment. While deities still officially have an alignment, and inhabit the Outer Plane matching that alignment, it's not clear that the deities are actively pursuing the furthering of their alignment for its own sake, aside from its presentation in their portfolio. The god of justice is furthering good and law, not because he is a god of good and law, but because he is a god of justice. He doesn't actively pursue other lawful or good things, like civilization or healing or whatever; Heironeous doesn't even grant the Life domain in the 5e Player's Handbook (2014).
It's also unclear that deities in 5e define alignments; alignment seems to be a force of the multiverse, and there's nothing to suggest that the gods define what alignment is. Even in older editions, when gods are able to change their own planar realm at will, there's a general lack of e.g. divinely created islands of one alignment in another plane, so it seems that the gods merely have alignment, and don't define it. Really old lore, i.e. AD&D 2e Guide to Hell, suggests that alignment was defined by beings who pre-date the gods. As it happens, Asmodeus is one of those beings, but only in the pre-4e context that Asmodeus is not a god.
In summary: By 5e-specific sources, gods don't define alignment, although they are defined or perceived in terms of it. Gods also don't actively promote their alignment, except in the context of their portfolio. However, D&D 3rd edition sources do depict some gods as having alignment elements as part of their portfolio.

In Forgotten Realms going back to 1e a god's followers did not always have the same alignment as their deity; warriors as followers of Tempus and magic users as followers of Mystra. Cleric alignments were restricted in 1e but loosened up over time as some deities alignments changed, eg Mystra from LN to CG without a portfolio change.

Going back a little earlier than the Guide to Hell, the Planescape setting established that alignments were defined by the consensus belief of every being in existence, and that the Rilmani (a race of extraplanar beings who embody neutrality in the same way that angels embody good and baatezu embody lawful evil) devoted a great deal of effort to preventing the consensus definitions of alignment from shifting over time.

But one should still consider that the gods are residing in a specific plane (Abyss, etc.) and these planes still are aligned to the old alignments... it's hard to kill a whole aspect of the old DnD 1st to 4th edition and hold on the stories. ;)

@MarcelGrüger Yes and no. It's true that a god's divine realm is usually on a plane corresponding to that god's alignment, but there's plenty of exceptions in every edition. The Norse pantheon all tend to hang out together on chaotic good Ysgard, for instance, but they aren't all chaotic good. (Also, fourth edition omitted four of the alignments for interesting but hugely unpopular reasons, and OD&D didn't have six of them because the good-evil alignment axis hadn't been introduced yet.)
